# What is the different application level and project level dictionary?

Tags: android

Some words show spelling error in my application. I add all of spelling error words save in to project level dictionary. When I add, that time it shows two option, one is project level and another is application level. My Question is:-

```
01. What is the different application level and project level dictionary?
02. Which one is better for uses?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) **Application level** dictionary is IDE level dictionary(you can say global dictionary for IDE). if you save a word to this dictionary, it will be accepted in all the projects/new Projects you open in the IDE.

Whereas if you add to **Project level** dictionary, it will be available only for that project. If you open new project, you have to add the word again.

2) Which one is better - It's completely depend on the words, if you have some words which you feel will be used across projects, use Application level dictionary.  If use have words which are particular to one project, use project level dictionary.

Comment: I had to search and learn this to be sure. I wish they named it "IntelliJ level" instead of "Application level". It'd been more clear to me. Application is a heavily overloaded term and quite ambiguous.